# How coming to the Bread for life relates to the Father's giving, in John 6

Tags: john

How does Jesus, in John 6, answer this question: “If someone has come, for life, to Jesus the Bread of life, (a) did he come as a result of the Father giving him to Jesus, or (b) did the Father give him to Jesus as a result of his coming to him?” ?

Comment: Which specific verse using the phrase "Bread for life" are you referring to?

Answer (score 1):

The question may reconstruct as follow

If someone come to Jesus

1. did he come as a result of the Father giving him to Jesus? or
2. did the Father give him to Jesus as a result of his coming to him?

So the question is asking who made the initiative. In the first scenario, the Father took the initiative, in the second, the person took the initiative.

Review John 6:65

> He (Jesus) went on to say, “This is why I told you that no one can come to me **unless the Father has enabled them.** (NIV)

The above verse may give an impression that it is the Father's determination. However in 2 Peter 3:9, we see everyone is given a fair chance to be saved.

> The Lord is not slow in keeping his promise, as some understand slowness. Instead he is patient with you, **not wanting anyone to perish, but everyone to come to repentance.** (NIV)

We find hope from James 4:8, that indicating that there is an interaction between human and God

> **Come near to God and he will come near to you**. Wash your hands, you sinners, and purify your hearts, you double-minded. (NIV)

Therefore if we take the initiative and determination to purify our hearts, and repent of our sins, God will response correspondingly and give us to Jesus. In Beatitudes Matthew 5:8, Jesus said,

> Blessed are the pure in heart, for they will see God. (NIV)

It is a blessing as well as a promise of God.

Comment: Interlinear 3rd edition Jay P. Green, Sr Editor Baker Books: "2 Peter 3:9"- The Lord...is long suffering toward us , not having purposed any [of us] to perish, but all [of us] to come to repentance". "us" is the church, the beloved of 2 Peter 3:1.  Also "us" 2 Peter 1:1 "those equally precious with us".

Comment: This interlinear puts in the brackets in its literal translation to show what it considers the "any" and "all" to refer to.

Comment: @C.Stroud - Thanks for the comment. I know the audiences of NT are believers, not non-believers. 2 Peter was a letter to the church for sure. However, the church is open to the public, does one go to the church is the one God gives Jesus? If this argument is true, then all letters in NT are redundant, for John 6:37 Jesus said "whoever comes to me I will never drive away". So if some of "us" in the church may not be people God gave Jesus, they have the same status as the non-believers, and therefore 2 Peter 3:9 is applicable to everyone, not only the church.

Comment: re: 2 Peter-"any" could be "any in the church" or "any in the world". "all" could be "all in the church "or "all in the world". The meaning of the verse depends upon which one of these one chooses. Some choose "any/all in the world" and I quoted an academic book which thinks "any/all in the church". Grammatically speaking I think that "any" and "all" both refer to "us" i.e. the church. So far I am looking at  grammar not theology.

Comment: @C.Stroud - I see. The way I usually look is the extents and limits the script applicable. Thanks for your words anyway.

Answer (score 0):

John 6:

> 37a All those the Father gives me will come to me

Let P1 be a person.

If the Father gives P1 to Jesus, P1 will come to Jesus.

Did he [P1] come as a result of the Father giving him to Jesus?

Yes.

> 37b whoever comes to me I will never drive away.

If P1 comes to me, then Jesus will not drive P1 away.

Assume that 37a and 37b are independent sentences. Each is complete in itself.

Did the Father give him [P1] to Jesus as a result of his [P1] coming to him [Jesus]?

If you assume 37a and 37b are independent, then no.

As John Rowse pointed out in his comment, the two clauses have different subjects and different actions. A case for their independence can be made.

Now assume that 37a and 37b are dependent since the two clauses are joined by the word "and".

John 6:37

> All those the Father gives me will come to me, **and** whoever comes to me I will never drive away.

If the Father gives P1 to Jesus, P1 will come to Jesus.

AND (the first-order logical AND operator)

If P1 comes to me, then Jesus will not drive P1 away.

Did the Father give him [P1] to Jesus as a result of his [P1] coming to him [Jesus]?

Now the two if-statements are declared true by AND.

If you assume 37a and 37b are dependent, then yes.

However still, strictly speaking, there is no formal causation relationship between the two. There is only an association (pair) relationship.

Comment: Thankyou for your answer, but could you please explain the second half? What do you mean by 37a and 37b being dependent/independent?

Comment: Good question. I added. Ask again if further questions.

Comment: Granted that in 37b, the action of the Son as Recipient and faithful Steward of the gifts is not independent of his relationship to the Father as Giver of the gifts in 37a, and the Father’s purpose in giving them to him, nevertheless, the two have different roles, which should not be confused. The “and” in v37 links statements with different subjects and different actions. 37a ascribes to the Father the initiating action of giving to the Son a group who all come, and 37b–40 states what, in obedience to his Father’s will, the Son does with his gifts now that they have come.

Comment: Good point. I added.

Answer (score 0):

The Lord speaks about the simultaneous reciprocation: it is both true that nobody comes to the Father but through the Lord Jesus Christ (John 14:6), and that nobody comes to the Lord Jesus Christ but through Father bringing him to Christ (Matthew 16:17-18; John 6:44; 17:6 /"You gave them to Me"/).

Therefore, the action of Christ bringing us to the Father and the action of the Father bringing us to Christ is one and the same divine action of two distinct divine realities or hypostases (as those realities were conveniently called later in IV century) in one God, + the action of the Holy Spirit, because it is only through the Latter that the Father conveys to us the vision of divinity of Christ (1 Cor. 12:3). Thus, the Trinity's Hypostases' activity drawing us to Each-Other, is one and the same tri-une activity.

If so, then the OP question should be radically reformulated, for when being drawn to one Trinitarian Hypostases by another Trinitarian Hypostasis, simultaneously we are drawn by the Latter Trinitarian Hypostasis to the Former Trinitarian Hypostasis, and since the action is simultaneous and reciprocal, there is no hierarchy between the Trinitarian Hypostases.

Comment: There is no call for that kind of Catholic jargon on an allegedly inductive site. christianity.se would love to hear all about your hypostasis ponderings.

Comment: @Ruminator I am not a Catholic, and all my words are based on the text of the Scriptures, as you salutarily fail to observe and appreciate. Trinitarian vision of God is a logical necessity coming out of conscientious reading of the Scriptures, the alternative is to strangle the breathing divine text with one’s narrow human agendum; but all such doomed attempts are at detriment of the stranglers themselves, their eternal salvation as a matter of fact.